# Angular $parse in filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have like of this inside a controller,

```
$scope.types = Array({'name': '...', 'condition: 'type=1'}, {'name': '...', 'type=2 or type>4'});
$scope.items = Array({'id': 1, 'name': 'A', 'type': 1 }, {'id': 8, 'name': 'B', 'type': 2 }, {'id': 123, 'name': 'C', 'type': 2 });
```

I also have an `ng-repeat` loop iterating over the `$scope.items`, together with a custom filter (piped with `| customFilter`). The customFilter can access the chosen `$scope.types` and iterates over all the items from `$scope.items`.

What I would like to do is to apply a string as a condition in order to be able to determine wether to filter this item or not, like this:

```
.filter('customFilter', function($parse) {

  return function(items, scope) {
    var filtered = [];
    if (_.isUndefined(scope.vm.type)) { // no need to filter
      return items;
    }
    var chkType = scope.vm.type.condition;
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
 //     var model = $parse(scope.vm.type.condition);
      var model = $parse("vm.type.condition");
      if (item.type === scope.vm.type[0]) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  } 
})
```

Could someone help me out here, to get this to work inside a loop inside a filter, or if there's a totally different approach? Thanks!

Comment: AngularJS version? What is `scope.vm`? How are you passing scope to the filter?

Comment: Angular 1.4.8. I pass scope by using

      return function(items, scope) {

in the filter's function, as seen above. By that I have access to the controller's scope-variable, defined as 

    .controller('searchCntrl', [function($parse) {
        var vm = this;
        ...

Does that help?

Comment: Don't you have `vm.types =` instead of `$scope.types = ` in your controller then? And what is `scope.vm.type`? I only see `vm.types` and `vm.items` in that case.

Comment: Can you add the controller code and the HTML to the question? Would be much easier to help.

Comment: Sorry for not providing all the code. However, I managed to figure out what was wrong. Here's my code (the relevant bit inside the filter):

      var isFound = $parse(scope.vm.type.condition);
      if (isFound(item)) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }


Thanks for having a look at this.

Comment: No problem, glad you solved it :)